# How to build my own 8V 6A PSU using laptop charger

Tags: power-supply

I have a 19V 4A laptop charger. I was wondering could I convert this into 8V 6A psu for my LEDs. They're parallel-only colour LEDs hence the high current demand.

Comment: Please use V and A and not v and a.

Answer (score 2):

It would be harder than starting from scratch.  Dropping 19V to 8V is fairly easy.  Increasing 4A to 6A is harder.  You would need DC to DC conversion circuit.  This is not easy and less so at that power level.

LEDs don't need real great power regulation.  You can run a transformer with enough current capacity to drive the LEDs and a full wave rectifier.  You can probably get by with very little if any filter caps.

Comment: Agreed. The powertrain in the adapter would make a good input stage for a buck converter to generate the 8V 6A, but reconfiguring the charger to give 8V at higher current goes beyond tinkering.

Comment: A buck DC/DC controller will give you automagically a higher output current than the input current if you step down from 19V to 8V.

Answer (score 2):

Linear Technology has a broad offer of SMPS controllers. Check [this page](http://www.linear.com/products/step-down_%28buck%29_regulators) for a parametric search.
One example which fits your requirements is the [LTC3611](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3611). It comes in a (for a buck controller) rather unusual QFN64 package, but doesn't require any external active components (MOSFETs).

[image]

If you don't like soldering QFN packages, Linear has an evaluation kit for this. (Hm, pretty steep price. I never took notice of price before, as Linear was always so generous as to give them to us for free.)

Answer (score 1):

Something that works with 'house-hold' components instead of QFN's. Something I've made about ten years ago. The values shown in the schematic will not be correct. You will have to calculate them yourself.

[image]

Comment: darn, the schematic is very unreadable. Any tips on how to post readable schematics are most welcome. Besides, this design works pretty well up to 20amps if needed.

Comment: You can right click on the schematic and choose 'save as'. It will give you an 150dpi image.

Comment: Or "view image" (at least in Firefox)